# Applescript audio input/output set if device is present

Tags: macos, audio, applescript

I have this script which currently will set audio inputs/outputs to a plantronics headset, but if the device is not plugged in the script will error. I need it to return text saying

> "Plug the device in"

if it isn't detected within the audio settings.

Here is the script:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to activate
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "input" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    tell table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
        select (row 1 where value of text field 1 is "Plantronics C725")
    end tell
end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to activate
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "output" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    tell table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
        select (row 1 where value of text field 1 is "Plantronics C725")
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must include your instruction "select..." into a try/end try block. I assume that you just have to do it for the "input" tab, because if "input" is OK, then the headset is connected and output tab should also be OK.

Replace the instruction :

```
select (row 1 where value of text field 1 is "Plantronics C725")
```

by :

```
try
select (row 1 where value of text field 1 is "Plantronics C725")
on error
display alert "headset not connected !"
return
end try
```

You can also change your code to repeat in case of error, but if you have an issue with your headset, the script may repeat forever !